# Why Christianity was "forked" from Judaism?

Tags: christianity, judaism

I was just interest why it happened that at the foundation of Christianity lies the Old Testament? It was just most authoritative religion 2000 years ago? Or any another reason?

Comment: Big question. Too big for this format. It's a book or two. Short answer, a good portion of Jews didn't want to accept the new theology involving jesus, so the Christians broadened their evangelism to everyone else. The remaining Jews held fast to that tradition of rejecting jesus as more than a plain teacher and still do today, while christianity turned out to be very popular over the ages with everyone else.

Comment: VTC as too basic. Christianity started as a Jewish movement. @fredsbend interesting viewpoint, where'd you get that from?

Comment: @john The part about converting Jews first? The book of Acts. Their own account is that "christ came for the Jews first, then the gentiles". The cynic in me sees "we aren't getting converts from the Jews, so let's target gentiles."

Comment: @fredsbend So they're your own ideas.

Comment: Had the first century Christians been as xenophobic as the Jews, they likely would have died out instead. Ironically, the openness to gentiles was probably a major reason Jews didn't convert over the ages, unless forced.

Comment: @john Not at all. There's *books* about this. That's why I flagged to close as too broad.

Comment: You’d want Christianity.se or a VERY well worded hermeneutics.se question.

Comment: Something not mentioned yet is that is that the Christian's claim of Jesus being the Messiah is rooted in Judiasm.  Without that foundation, claim of divinity, and all that went with it, it's likely that he'd be seen as just another philosopher and/or cult leader, of which Rome had a (super) abundance.  Compare the 19th century foundation of Mormonism as a fork of Christianity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was just interest why it happened that at the foundation of Christianity lies the Old Testament?

Christianity began as a split within Judaism, so that seems fairly logical.

> It was just most authoritative religion 2000 years ago?

No, far from it. Judaism was one of the many religions in the region. In the area of the bible countries (now: Israel, Syria, Egypt etc.) there were many more religions, but Judaism was locally the most important religion.

In some areas (Jerusalem, Galilee) it was the most dominant religion, in other areas it was not. The whole area was a patchwork of very different religions. Samaritans didn't get along with the Jews, whole areas were completely Greek. Greeks and Jews were often at odds. As far as I know Baal was worshiped in several places.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this wouldn't belong more on another site.  But one thing to consider is that Judaism is not a very proselytizing religion - it's tough to convert to and is really aimed at people of Jewish ancestry.

On the other hand, Christianity aims to convert people to it.  So, rather than "just" a question of doctrine, as you can see with various branches of Islam and Christianity evolving, the notion of appealing to non-Jews would just not fit in with core Judaism.